# Dojo form.Select not setting value properly

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a problem with the dijit.formSelect, I'm not able to set the selected option. I'm creating the array with all the options dynamically, and setting the 'selected' field to true if the condition is met. This part is fine, when inspecting the created array it is as expected. The problem comes when I perform the select.addOption. In that case it drops the selected = true from the original element and sets the first element of the array, which is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
var select = dijit.byId("nameOfThe form.Select");
var arrayOptions = [];

//Data is another array with more information
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
newOption = {
    value: data[i][ident],
    label: data[i][label]
};

if(exist(currentValue[0]) && currentValue[0] == data[i][ident]) {
    newOption.selected = true;
}

arrayOptions.push(newOption);
}

select.addOption(arrayOptions);
```

I'm following the tutorials and several forums and I have tried the things that they say, like:

- select.set("value", "value wanted"); // As a string
- select.set("value", value wanted); // As a number
- select.value = "value wanted";
- select.setDisplayedValue(value wanted)

Nothing works, and it's driving me crazy. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After adding the OPTIONs to the SELECT, you might have to set the `selectedIndex` property:

```
var select = dijit.byId("nameOfThe form.Select");
var arrayOptions = [];
var selectedIndex = 0;

//Data is another array with more information
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    newOption = {
        value: data[i][ident],
        label: data[i][label]
    };

    if(exist(currentValue[0]) && currentValue[0] == data[i][ident]) {
        selectedIndex = i;
    }

    arrayOptions.push(newOption);
}

select.addOption(arrayOptions);
select.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
```

Comment: Hm. The only other alternative is to add each OPTION inside the for-loop, and at the end set the selectedIndex. If that's not working, is there other code on the page that is changing the SELECT box after you have modified it?

Comment: That doesn't work either, in my code there is not interference in that sense. Actually when debugging the code, it adds the selected=true to the first element when performing the select.addOption regardless I'm using it once at the end or inside a loop. I'm going to try debugging the component itself

Comment: You might have to dive into good 'ol DOM methods: document.createElement("option") and select.appendChild(...).